# Why does a for loop invoke a warning when using identical code?

Tags: c++

I think that following two codes are identical. but upper one has C4715 "not all control paths return a value" problem and other doesn't.
Why this warning happens?

```
int func(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
        if(n == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

```
int func(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the warning say?

Comment: c4715 not all control paths return a value

Comment: The codes aren't actually _"identical"_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ they have the same observable behaviour

Comment: The compiler isn't clever enough to see through the loop. So its conservative in the second case as there's some paths where its possible for there to be no return. (Obviously not in practice though)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `for` loop is dummy - compiler will optimize it away when optimization is enabled. From this point of view it is identical.

Comment: @kims [edit] your question in order to add more information when requested, that's not the purpose of comments.

Comment: The first version happens to return early inside the `for` loop but there's no return statement after the loop which the compiler complains about. The 2nd version has a return in both the if and else (and no for loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is trying to be helpful, and failing. Pretend for a moment that the code inside the loop was just `if (n == 0) return 0;`. Clearly, when `n` is not 0, the loop will execute once and then execution will move on to the next statement after the loop. There's no `return` statement there, and that's what the compiler is warning you about. It just isn't smart enough to see that the code inside the loop always returns.

So, possibly, add a `return 0;` statement after the loop. That might make the compiler happy. But it also might make the compiler (or some other compiler) give a different warning about "unreachable code", because that new `return` statement can't actually be reached. This stuff is hard to analyze, and compilers often get it wrong.

Comment: I'm not convinced its failing. If we ignore the extra information an optimising compiler would have [values of variables and loop bounds, etc] then the first one  has a path through it that doesn't have a return, and the second doesn't. So its always right to warn in the first case. This is an _obvious_ example where a warning isn't needed but you can make the bounds calculation arbitrarily complex until even the smartest compiler cant work it out. IMO a compiler which warns about unreachable code after applying optimisations (however trivial) is wrong.

Comment: As in that case, small changes to optimisation settings or environments can cause this to be a heisen-error.

Comment: @MikeVine -- I completely agree that if the code was different the answer might be different,.

Answer (score 0):

Because warnings don't promise to only flag incorrect code. Nor do they promise to flag all incorrect code. It's [not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) to be completely accurate.

It seems like the part of the compiler that issues C4715 assumes that a for loop with an end condition ends in some cases, and doesn't try to calculate if it will always return early.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought is that the loop cannot act.

You initialize the `for` loop with `int i = 0` then give bounds of `i < 1` with an action if `i++`

Given `i` is type int with step of 1, it can never loop.

Comment: If it didn't have the early return, the code would loop exactly once. The first time through, `i` is 0, so it satisfies `i < 1`.